# Algorithms Runtime complexity:

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

At careercup site, there was this problem (https://careercup.com/question?id=6270877443293184):

```
Given an array, find the number of tuples such that
A [i] + A [j] + A [k] = A [l] in an array, where i <j <k <l.
```

The proposed solution (below) there works but state runtime complexity of O(n^2). After analyzing the code, I don't think it can be done in less than n^2 * log n. My rationale is that it iterates through all elements in the 2d array (which is n^2 and them in a list that contains the tuples, check for each one, which is O(n). Even using TreeMap and doing a binary search can only reduce is to log n, not to constant time. Can someone confirm if this can be done in O(n^2) and explain me what is incorrect in my logic?

Proposed solution:

```
Fill 2 2d arrays with
arr1[i][j]=a[i]+a[j]
arr2[i][j]=a[j]-a[i]
j>i
In a map<int,list<int>>, map[arr1[i][j]].push_back(j)
For each element in arr2, search in the map.
Count all hits where j < k
```

Comment: Your problem description is cut off.

Comment: Sorry. Just fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty easy to insert `j` in increasing order in `map[arr1[][]]`.

If you enumerate each element in arr2 in increasing k order you don't you have to do a binary search. You can just enumerate all the `j`.

Because you are going in increasing `k` order, for each list in the map you just have to remember where was the last one that you saw. So the map should rather be a `map<int, <int, list<int>>>`.

Since you only touch each `j` once and your complexity is only `O(n^2)`.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, in the worst case this is not `O(n^2)`.

The author obviously assumed that `list` from `map<int,list<int>>` would contain only few members; it is the assumption similar to the one that we use when we state that the complexity of `find` operation of a hash table is `O(1)`. Recall, a hash table whose collision resolution is based on [separate chaining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Separate_chaining_with_linked_lists) has a constant complexity of `find` operation on average, but in case when many elements hash to the same value it can degrade to a linear complexity.

Implementation-wise, notice that map `map<int,list<int>>` needs to be a hash table (i.e. `std::unordered_map` in C++, `HashMap` in Java), not `std::map` (or `TreeMap` in Java) because with `std::map` just the `find` operation is `O(logn)`.